# pick a file with javascript (chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Let's say I have form with `<input type="file" name="file1" id="foo">`. Is it possible to return a file dialog result into this input somehow using javascript?

I guess it's working that way:
When you choose file chrome copy that file into some some kind of folder "temp" and when you submit form chrome send it to the server, but is it possible to change path into full path somehow or my only chance is to first copy all files into google temp folder and then add file with js

Does anyone know where is path to file stored after i pick file?

Answer (score 0):

Files added through a file selection dialog remain in the same location until you press submit. after that, a copy is handled by whatever JS code is behind the file selector. there is no use of a temp folder or anything of temporary storage. and if your input type is file, you don't need to do anything special, the file dialog is automatically linked to it.

Maybe I understand the question wrong though. And no, it is not possible to access the file system using Javascript. if this were possible, it would be a massive security risk. You need to have user interaction to upload files.

Comment: So i can change full path? Nice... I will report results after some time hacking.

Comment: lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 22 2013 17:31:50 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
name: "langs.jpg"
size: 305238
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: "" - that how file is stored. There's no full path anywhere :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **[File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)**. Simple way to use it is to listen to `change` event of your input

```
document.getElementyById('foo').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
}, false);
```

Then you can use the `FileReader` to deal with the files

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
```

Caution! This example is very simplified. You might want to read **[this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)** article to get the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 // select the file input (using a id would be faster)
 $('input[type=file]').change(function() { 
// select the form and submit
$('form').submit(); 
});
```

or

There is a nice way to upload files via AJAX. You can try this [Click Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/)